# Windows Phone 8 IconicTemplate Tile Images show blank

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8

I'm developing a Windows Phone 8 app and testing it on Lumia 920. I selected two images, one 71x110 and one 134x202 for IconicTemplate from WMAppManifest.xml and deployed it on the device.

When the app is pinned to start screen, the tile shows white rectangles instead of the images. Strangely, the tile can correctly show the white spiky circle images that come with sdk samples when they are selected as tile images. What can I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the non-transparent parts of a png show up as white and nothing else, so basically it seems you can only create a shape using the "Iconic" tile template, much like the default tiles that come installed on Windows 8 phones.

The solution is to switch to the "Flip" tile template instead.

Answer (score 2):

Bumped on this few days ago as well. It turns out that Iconic Tile Template is only displaying white on transparent images and no other colors are possible in this case.

Is it possible that there is no proper documentation about this restriction nowhere online.

I would highly appreciate if someone can provide me with details.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of images you use? Jpg or png with transparent background? Make sure the image is png and also you reference them properly in your method. It's also recommended to use only white and transparent colors on iconic images.

Answer (score 1):

If Martins suggestion does not work, you can also check the properties of the image. Be sure the Build Action is set to Content.